# osm2pgsql : How to store "nd ref" data to a column in PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm using osm2pgql to import an OSM map. I imported it successfully but I need also the information in the "nd ref" node of the OSM XML.

I.e. my OSM XML has a node like:

```
<way id='1805' action='modify' visible='true'>
    <nd ref='27625' />
    <nd ref='27943' />
    <nd ref='27646' />
    <nd ref='27647' />
    <nd ref='27648' />
    <nd ref='27781' />
    <nd ref='27755' />
    <nd ref='27819' />
    <nd ref='27628' />
    <nd ref='27627' />
    <nd ref='27626' />
    <nd ref='27625' />
    <tag k='amenity' v='toilets' />
    <tag k='female' v='yes' />
    <tag k='indoor' v='room' />
    <tag k='level' v='0' />
    <tag k='level_name' v='parter' />
    <tag k='name' v='Toaleta damska na parterze' />
  </way>
```

So is there a way to also store this info

```
<nd ref='27625' />
    <nd ref='27943' />
    <nd ref='27646' />
    <nd ref='27647' />
    <nd ref='27648' />
    <nd ref='27781' />
    <nd ref='27755' />
    <nd ref='27819' />
    <nd ref='27628' />
    <nd ref='27627' />
    <nd ref='27626' />
    <nd ref='27625' />
```

in a specific column on the line table?

Comment: The "nd ref" means "node reference". The nd refs in the XML for a way tell which nodes are making the way. I think it does not make much sense to save the node references as attributes of a line geometry because there may be thousands of nodes in a linestring. And that information is already available from the "middle" tables https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#database-structure. When the way id is knows the list of nodes can be queried from the OSM_ways table. And further, also the information about each node like in the API call https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/1163297514/full.

Comment: Hello @user30184, thanks for your comment. Anyway, I cannot see in my db those reference information. I have just these tables in my Postgres: lines, points, polygons, roads... so there is no "ways" table. I'm wondering if I'm wronging sth while import the osm with osm2pgsql... any more advice?

Comment: Did you run osm2pgsql in the slim mode https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html? That mode writes and keeps the nodes, ways, relations, and users tables in the database.

Comment: Yes, just discovered that. Added --slim to the command and now I have all data! Thanks for your support!